# Regex - split string with delimiters into groups

Tags: javascript, regex

It's needed to parse strings like:

1. `object/custom/name1/name2`
2. `object/custom/name1/name2/typea`
3. `object/custom/name1/name2/typea/item`

The result I'm expected to get is:
`group1: name1/name2`
`group2: typea`
`group3: item`

Only `group1` (the group with name) is required. Other groups (2,3) are optional. It depends on the string. E.g. for the first string should be present only first group with the string `name1/name2`.

The string `typea` is static strings.

Here is the link with the playground: https://regex101.com/r/j1ay1s/1/
Or regex: `object\/(custom|standard)\/(.*)(?:\/(typea|typeb))(?:\/(.*))?`

Comment: if the structure is stable you can just `const [o, c, n1, n2, t, i] = s.split('/');` (`t` and `i` will be undefined if they don't exist.)

Comment: The name2 can be absent. In that case, group1 should contain only name1 param.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get 3 capturing groups making the second and third optional, use a character class for `type[ab]` and don't use a capturing group for `(custom|standard)`

```
object\/(?:custom|standard)\/(.*?(?=\/type[ab]|$))(?:\/(type[ab])(?:\/(.*))?)?
```

**Explanation**

- `object\/(?:custom|standard)\/` Match `object/custom/` or `object/standard/`
- `(.*?(?=\/type[ab]|$))` Caputure in **group 1** as least as possible characters until you encounter typea or typeb or the end of the string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\/(type[ab])` Match `/` and capture in **group 2** either `typea` or `typeb`
  - `(?:\/(.*))?` Optional non capture group, match `/` and capture in **group 3** the rest of the line
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vq6phW/1)